# Django website trouble accessing models to make queries to the database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a dietary tracker website which will use Django, python, sql etc. When I try to access the models to make queries to the database, it gives a long error. I am running the test file in my vs code terminal and am using a macbook pro.

```
/opt/anaconda3 /bin/python /Desktop/dietary_app/tests.py

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/Desktop/dietary_app/tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models import Food_Table
  File "/Desktop/dietary_app/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Participant(models.Model): 
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 129, in __new__
     app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
     self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured( 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Example program I used to make the queries:

```
from models import Food_Table
food_names = Food_Table.objects.all('food_name', flat=True)
print(food_names)
```

The model I am trying to pull data from:

```
class Food_Table(models.Model): 
    food_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key = True) 
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40) 
    food_description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
```

Comment: Check your `settings.py` file.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

Answer (score 2):

> I am running the test file in my vs code terminal and am using a macbook pro.

[Calling `django.setup()` is required for “standalone” Django usage.<sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

```
from django.conf import settings
from myapp import myapp_defaults  # <—- myapp is probably one of your apps which you need to get some default settings to make use of.

settings.configure(default_settings=myapp_defaults, DEBUG=True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    django.setup() # <—- must be called only once hence put in if block.

#•••The rest of your script•••
```

Answer (score 0):

Point to the settings file via the settings environment variable in your `manage.py` like this:

```py
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'dietary_app.settings')
```